# power on by mouse not working after installing windows 10

Tags: windows-10, mouse

I had until this week Windows 7  and I was turning on my PC.

Via my mouse in the bios is set up to power on the pc by mouse

Now I have installed Windows 10 and it's not working.

I have updated all drivers and everything looks OK, but it's still not working.

What could the problems are?